# align-items: center - not centering things precisely

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using `display: flex`, `align-items: center` to center things vertically - it's kinda centering things, but not exactly. Not sure why it's not being precise. it's skewed to top:

[image]

What could be causing this error?

```
.conA {
height: 100vh;
display: flex; 
align-items: center  ;
}


<section class="conA">
<div id="container">
<div id="heroText">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
 <div id="text"><div id="cursor"></div></div>
 </div>
 <div id="images"></div>
 </div> 
  </section>
```

Update: more code

```
body {
font-family: gotham;
margin: 0px  !important;
color: #827F88;
letter-spacing: 0.4px; 
line-height: 1.9;
}

p, h3, .title, .intro  {
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

we'd need to know the complete CSS to answer your question, but the reason obviously is that your flex container (`.conA`) only contains **one flex item**, i.e. `#container`, so the flex settings in this case won't have much effect. All the other elements are *children*  ot that flex item, and the flex settings won't apply to grandchildren.

Your question code is different from the result image you posted, but taking the code posted in your question, you can fix the problem by taking the `#images` div out of the `#container` div and use the following code:

```css
.conA {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<section class="conA">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="heroText">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      <div id="text">
        <div id="cursor"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="images"><img src="https://placehold.it/300x200"></div>
</section>
```